# Слайдер прокрутка вправо

Tags: bootstrap

Как в стандартном слайдере `Bootstrap` поставить прокрутку слайдов слева направо?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962585/bootstrap-carousel-slide-left-to-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## "Восточная карусель" с прокруткой в обратном направлении

Если [добавить слайдеру атрибут](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-4) `data-slide="prev"`, то слайдер перейдёт на предыдущий слайд только один раз - сразу после загрузки страницы. А затем смена слайдов пойдёт в обычном направлении.

---

### jQuery

На английском SO есть два скрипта:

1. [скрипт попроще](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32521696/6263942) прокручивает слайды в обратном направлении, но не трогает индикаторы;
2. [скрипт посложнее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877563/6263942) меняет и направление прокрутки, и порядок индикаторов:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').each(function(){
        $(this).carousel();

        var carousel = $(this).data('bs.carousel'); // or .data('carousel') in bootstrap 2
        carousel.pause();

        // At first, reverse the order of the items in the carousel because we're moving backwards
        $(this).find('> .carousel-inner > .item:not(:first-child)').each(function() {
            $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
        });

        // Override the bootstrap carousel prototype function, adding a different one won't work (it'll work only for the first slide)
        carousel.cycle = function (e) {
            if (!e) this.paused = false
            if (this.interval) clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.options.interval
            && !this.paused
            && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.prev, this), this.options.interval))
            return this;
        };

        carousel.cycle();
    });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#myCarousel img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

### CSS

Сделал то же самое с помощью стилей, без скриптов и перестановок в HTML.

1. растягиваем слайды на всю ширину контейнера;
2. меняем порядок индикаторов с помощью `float: right;` и заново выравниваем их по центру слайда;
3. меняем анимацию при смене слайдов.

Проверьте, пожалуйста:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/dzotg9pv/)
   [codepen](http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/LZGPbz)
   [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/6ncjaAcz4v)

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* 1 */
#myCarousel img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* 2 */
.carousel-indicators {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  float: right;
  margin: 1px 4px;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
  margin: 0 3px;
}

/* 3 */
@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=1" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=2" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=3" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```